# A word for treating all deviating instances in the same way

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word for when you apply the same treatment to any object that possesses some measurable quality, regardless of its measure.

For example, we work at a potato chip (crisp) plant and are tasked with inspecting the bags. If we find that some bags deviate from the expected weight too much, we throw them in the trash. I wrote

> A lot of chips are lost because we discard the deviant bags without scrutiny.

But we are scrutinizing the bags, we just aren't adapting our treatment of the bags according to their individual properties - for instance, if a bag weighs too much instead of too little, maybe it would be smarter to eat it for lunch or do whatever with it. But we're just throwing them in the trash, without _______.

> Or perhaps we are wondering what film to watch tonight. We apply the rule "only movies with a 90%+ rating on RT", ignoring the rest without ______.

*Closer inspection*? Doesn't really work for the same reason - we may be identifying the deviant bags/low-rated films after super close inspection. What's interesting is what we do *after* inspecting them.

Comment: Treating alike is treating without *discrimination*.

Comment: In an *egalitarian way* would emphasise the equality.

Comment: I like both but in a sense they both have a sort of positive connotation. Egalitarian, non-discriminatory. Sounds like a nice guy!

Comment: IMHO, *without discrimination* has neither positive nor negative connotation in itself. *Non-discriminatory* is positive - but *undiscriminating* is certainly negative.

Comment: I think discrimination works best too. You could also flipthe sentence round and say that the rules are being applied too *rigidly*.

Comment: Following up on Michael's comment: You could drop the word 'without', and just say 'indiscriminately'.

Comment: You are applying a *gate* or, pardon the pun, a *one size fits all* approach.

Comment: You are discarding the bags rather than selling them to the employees.  At the Miller Beer brewery in Milwaukee they sell underweight cans and cartons to the employees in the company store.

Comment: see John Hanna's answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100208/meaning-of-blunt-instrument

Answer (score 3):

You are treating all instances *without **exception***.

Your examples:

> But we're just throwing them in the trash, without ***exception***.
>
> We apply the rule "only movies with a 90%+ rating on RT", ignoring the
> rest without ***exception***.

**ODO:**

> **[exception](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exception)**
> *NOUN*
>
> A person or thing that is **excluded from a general statement** or
> does not follow a rule.
>
> ‘he always plays top tunes, and tonight was no exception’
> ‘the
> administrator made an exception in the Colonel's case and waived the
> normal visiting hours’
>
> **[without exception](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/without_exception)**
> *PHRASE*
>
> With no one or nothing excluded.
>
> ‘almost without exception, all the
> residents are opposed to this vandalism’
>
> ‘The law will be applied without exception, notably in public places.’

If a phrase is acceptable, you can use ***second thought(s)*** in the sense of **closer inspection**.

> But we're just throwing them in the trash, without ***second thought***.
>
> We apply the rule "only movies with a 90%+ rating on RT", ignoring the
> rest without ***second thoughts***.

**ODO:**

> **[second thoughts](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/second_thoughts)** (US **second thought**)
> *PLURAL NOUN*
>
> A change of opinion or resolve reached after considering something
> again.
>
> ‘on second thoughts, perhaps he was right’

Comment: I think *without discrimination* feels slightly better tbh.